# Get Value of first Pair

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this file

```
Date      | Time         | Table  |      Checkin Time | Bill Number ..| .. |
7/1/2018   **18:03:48**   **6**         **18:03:48**       **4332**
7/1/2018   18:11:23       **6**         **18:03:48**       **4332**
7/1/2018   18:23:10       **6**         **18:03:48**       **4332**
7/1/2018   19:24:11         8             19:24:11           4333
7/1/2018   19:56:17         8             19:24:11           4333
7/1/2018   20:31:11        *6             20:31:11           4332*
```

I need to calculate Checkin Time which is 1st time of table number and bill number.
For example See one customer checkin at `18:03:48` with `table number 6` 
His `Bill number` is `4332` .
So for `table number 6` and `Bill number 4332` `chekin time` will be 1st `time` 
which is `18:03:48`. 
So I applied the formula:

```
=IF(AND(E3=E2,C3=C2,A3=A2),D2,MIN(OFFSET(E3,0,-3,MATCH(0,(E3:E$35470=E3)*(C3:C$35470=C3)*(A3:A$35470=A3),0)-1,1)))
```

But the value changes at `6th row` . 
It's giving `20:31:11` as `checkin time` . 
It should be `18:03:48` because the `6th row table number and bill number` is same as 1st one. 
So How do I make it possible, to calculate the `checkin time` as per `1st time` who have same `bill and table number` , no matter which row . 
Here is the excel [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11F3glaecWXeX9-GAG4HJH7O9SG-Xb8E9/view?usp=sharing) I have uploaded to Google drive. 
Here is the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/djKZcK).

Edit:- Formula by @jeeped work, But as the log is of 30 days
The data keeps repeating the other day too. 
Can it be done by giving some `unique` date value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeeped's answer is spot on, here is an adjustment for the formula to work over multiple days that have the same table numbers and bill numbers:

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, ((A$2:A$13)+(B$2:B$13))/((C$2:C$13=C2)*(E$2:E$13=E2)*(A$2:A$13=A2)), 1)
```

All I did was add this extra conditional argument, that checks if the "Date" is the same:

```
*(A$2:A$13=A2)
```

[image: CheckInTime]

Comment: As usual @girlvsdata You are the savior . Thank you so much... I was just filtering and applying formula each day, had 4 months data. But you saved me AGAIN. Thank you so much...

Comment: @ジョシアヌズ No worries, happy to help. I can't take all the credit for this one, Jeeped did most of the work!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the newer MINIFS and MAXIFS, use AGGREGATE to achieve the same result.

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, ((A$2:A$7)+(B$2:B$7))/((C$2:C$7=C2)*(E$2:E$7=E2)), 1)
```

Format the result any way you want; as date and time, time only, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It did exactly what I wanted. I was afraid, the data would be same if I changed the day, Like I have logs of 3 months. But it didnt change, I do have newer version of excel too which have MINIFS and MAXIFS. can you also tell me how to do using those formula? But thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of an array formula combining `INDEX`+`MATCH` to return the earliest time value that matches your conditions first. In cell D2, enter the following:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(1,($C$2:$C$7=C2)*($E$2:$E$7=E2),0))
```

When returning, be sure to press `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of just `ENTER` to make sure the formula calculates correctly.

Comment: Despite the sample data, I believe that the day must be considered a factor and the data may not necessarily be sorted by date/time ascending.

Comment: @Jeeped, correct. I should've disclosed that the formula is based on the assumption that data are chronologically entered from earliest date and time at the top going below.

Comment: @Jeeped It worked with your formula too. But there is 30 days to count of. as you can see 07/01/2018 , it ends until 07/01/2018 . And what I saw is that everytime the table number and bill number is same(no matter which day) , `checkin time` still takes the time of 1st day. :(